# What is the entitlement "Data Protection" good for when creating an Apple App ID?

Tags: ios, data-protection

I have always been using the best possible data protection in my iOS apps. This means I saved all my files with the flag “available when unlocked, this  device only”. Back then this "just worked". Now I have found that there is a new setting when creating an App ID (see screenshot) where I can explicitly enable data protection.

This is how I understand the new option. Can somebody please confirm?

- If it is enabled it seems as if all files inside the documents folder will be protected automatically using the selected protection mode. Correct?
- If it is disabled, can I still set the flags using `NSFileManager`?

[image]

Comment: did you solve this question? I'm under the same situation...

Comment: I'm a newbie to iOS!!!. I have enabled this option and i submitted my app they had rejected with the following review msg " Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines or they will be rejected" Can you please guide is they are related. pls reply soon.

Comment: You should ask Apple why they rejected your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If it is enabled it seems as if all files inside the documents folder
  will be protected automatically using the selected protection mode.
  Correct? - YES
- If it is disabled, can I still set the flags using NSFileManager? -
  YES
- if it is enabled, can I still set the flags using NSFileManager? - YES

You can test it by try to download the application content.